# jQuery - Identify td that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom, click

I have created a grid `(table)` inside of an HTML doc based on user preference.

After appending the `rows` and `cells` to the table, it appears jQuery cannot access them properly? Its as if it doesn't consider them part of the `DOM`.

Essentially I will be handling everything inside of a multidimensional array for my data, such as:

`[ ["","",""], ["","",""], ["","",""] ]`

It is currently set up with appended rows named `#row_0, #row_1, etc` and `td`'s added without an `ID`.

I need to be able to map the `clicked TD` to my jQuery so I can perform some functions and logic on it.

**Is there any way to respond to my JS when a user clicks on a `td` with something like:**

`tr = [1]`

`td = [2]`

**Current code found here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/HNjMR/4/

Comment: Unrelated (possibly) note... why does it bring up a blinking cursor in my table...?

Answer (score 3):

Here live example friend: http://jsfiddle.net/HNjMR/5/

```
$("#board").on('click', 'td', function(){
    $("#board td").css("background","white");
    $(this).css("background","red");
});
```

This happens because when you insert a new dynamic element on the page, ready jquery can not find it. The ready by default runs events only on existing elements at load time. While some functions like .on, solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

when the `td` element click handler is added those target elements are not yet created so use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and bind the click handler to the `#board` element with the target element selector as `td` as given below. Then use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the position of row and td(Add 1 to index as it is 0 based)

```
$("#board").on('click', 'td', function () {
    var $td = $(this);
    var td = $td.index() + 1,
        row = $td.parent().index() + 1;
    alert(td + '-' + row);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cmja8/)

---

Also your create code is buggy, jQuery append does not work like string concatenation

```
$('#board tr').remove();
var size = parseInt($("#size").val());
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr />', {
        id: 'row_' + i
    }).data('index', i + 1);
    $("#board").append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'>");
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        $('<td />', {
            id: 'col_' + j
        }).data('index', j + 1).appendTo($tr);
    }
    $("#board").append($tr);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ttzt9/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/898n2/1/

```
$( document ).on( "click", "td", function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

This is using your current code

Notice I have used .on - this is a 'live' event using jquery

I have also modified your naming of each td to read col_1_2 - with 1 being col and 2 being row.

```
        $("#row_"+i).append("<td id='col_"+j+"_"+i+"'>&nbsp;</td>");
```

Comment: I have Javascript as far as logic goes, but learning to manipulate the DOM is still a bit shaky. Thank you for your assistance :-) It's very helpful to see improved ways and methods to do things.

Comment: Glad I could help - you can always upvote my answer if you like it (or accept it if it serves your purpose!)

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution, remember that you should bind the eventclick when the elements was created,  you souldn't use a generical $('td').click event, this does not work because some elements was not added in DOM yet.

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    var size = $("#size").val();
    if(size<3 || size>10){
        alert("That is not a valid input. Please select 3-10");
        return;
    }

    $('#board tr').remove();

    // Check this bellow
    var size = parseInt($("#size").val()), 
    tr = $("<tr/>"), td = $("<td/>"), tdc;

    for(var i=0;i < size;i++){    
        for(var j=0;j<size;j++){
            tdc = td.clone();
            tdc.attr('id', 'col_'+j);
            tr.append(tdc);

            tdc.click(function(){
                alert(this);
            });
        }

        tr.attr('id','row_'+i);

        $("#board").append(tr);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah ! congrats bro !